# How do I install drivers for a Lexmark X6675 Printer?

Tags: lexmark

I have a problem installing [Lexmark X6675 driver](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=DR20523&docLocale=en_US&segType=recommendedSegmentLINUX_UNIX) on Precise and have problem.

The package has a blank line in `Description` field which wasn't a problem all the way up to Oneiric but it is a problem on Precise.

```
Extracting file: printdriver.te
Extracting file: lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
Extracting file: launcher.c
Extracting file: launcher
Extracting file: lsbrowser
Extracting file: lsusbdevice
Using dpkg installation
=============================
Execute: dpkg -i --force-architecture lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb > /tmp/selfgz11978/pkg/files/dpkg_msgs

dpkg: error processing lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb (--install):
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 9 package 'lexmark-08z-series-driver':
 blank line in value of field 'Description'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
=============================

=============================
Execute: rm lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb

=============================
***** ERROR REPORT *****
```

Is there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my solution with Lexmark x4650 driver. Adjust to your needs.

Please execute the commands **one by one**:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs xz-lzma
wget http://downloads.lexmark.com/downloads/cpd/lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.tar.gz -O lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.tar.gz
tar xzvf lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.tar.gz
./lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh --noexec --target lexmark
cd lexmark
tar xJvf instarchive_all
dpkg-deb -I lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
mkdir raw-lexmark-archive
dpkg-deb --raw-extract lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb raw-lexmark-archive
sed -i "/^ $/d" raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control
cat raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b ./raw-lexmark-archive fixed-lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i fixed-lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
```

To remove the package run:

```
sudo dpkg -P lexmark-08z-series-driver:i386
```

all works, but when you go to add the ppd files, it's in `/home/lexmark/raw-lexmark-archive/usr/local/lexmark/08zero/ect`

For the x4650, choose `lx36-46.ppd`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer above:
Download http://www.mediafire.com/?yowom7gh6vg4fzl - Install and enjoy
Used 1.0.4 version.

Note: Not sure about copyright, I waive any copyright claims, the software is copyrighted to Lexmark.