# Ubuntu 12.04 driver for Lexmark x4650

Tags: lexmark

Does anyone have a driver (or other way to connect to) a Lexmark x4650 wireless network printer?

Comment: a link to the fixed driver as i dont see it linked here. as for scanning doesnt USB work? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_eMUZWzi-namQ2dzlPWjlneG8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

The x4650 worked perfectly in 10.04. I got printing to work but no luck with the scanner

For printing see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130516/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-a-lexmark-x6675-printer).

The main instructions are outlined below:

- Install `fixed-lexmark-1.0-1.i386.deb`
- Run:

  ```
  sudo chown -Rh root:root /usr/local/lexmark
  ```
- Add printer with cups by going to `http://localhost:631` in your web browser and giving your logon username and password as credentials.
- Give this URL: socket://192.168.2.6:9100 (AppSocket/HP JetDirect )
- Provide a PPD File: `/usr/local/lexmark/08zero/etc/lx36-46.ppd` (lx36-46.ppd)

Anybody got a fix for the scanner?