# Install printer Lexmark X4690 (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, wine, printing, lexmark

I am using ubuntu 12.04, and tried to install a printer without sucess (Lexmark X4690) but it seems that this printer is no longer compatible as the last software available was to ubuntu 10, but did not work with ubuntu 12. I installed the driver using wine, but I don't know if its possible to use it that way. Does anyone now if it's possible and how to proceed in this specific case?

http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=product&locale=EN&productCode=LEXMARK_X4690&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN#1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. See the link:

[How do I install drivers for a Lexmark X6675 Printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130516/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-a-lexmark-x6675-printer)

or download the file directly:

http://www.mediafire.com/?yowom7gh6vg4fzl